# NestJS Before create record select collection name dynamic

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am working on NestJS Project, there are different collection like Customer_${uuid}, before insert record collection name select base on input.

My input like :

```
{
  cusomer_uuid: 'asdfas-asdf-asdf-asdf',
  value: {
     action: 'UPDATE',
     value: 'test'

  }
}
```

Data insert into collection name `customer_${cusomer_uuid}`

Answer (score 2):

**You can also create and select using this mechanism**

```
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
export class User{
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection() private connection: Connection
  ) {}

async create(){
  await this.connection.collection('collectionName').insertOne({
  "name":"demo",
  "age":25
});
}}
```

Comment: Using this method data is inserted but index of collection is not generated.